# epub2pdf paginate the html format

Tags: objective-c, c, pdf, epub

I am working on a project which needs to convert epub to pdf.

I am stuck on how to paginate the html format.

Can someone give me some idea? is there any open source libs to paginate the html like the print review in most browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to convert to LaTeX, and let that do the typesetting.